# Ubuntu 16.04 crashes while running store operation in PIG grunt shell

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop2

Everytime when I trigger LOAD command followed by STORE command in the PIG grunt shell. My system crashes as soon as the MapReduce phase starts in the PIG.

I have triggered following commands before starting the PIG grunt shell in MapReduce Mode.

```
start-dfs.sh  
start-yarn.sh  
mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver
```

Following are the logs of above operation:

```
16/08/11 10:56:32 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable  
Starting namenodes on [localhost]  
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-devesh-ThinkPad-L412.out  
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-devesh-ThinkPad-L412.out  
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]  
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-secondarynamenode-devesh-ThinkPad-L412.out  
16/08/11 10:56:50 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable  
starting yarn daemons  
starting resourcemanager, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/yarn-hadoop-resourcemanager-devesh-ThinkPad-L412.out  
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/yarn-hadoop-nodemanager-devesh-ThinkPad-L412.out  
starting historyserver, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/mapred-hadoop-historyserver-devesh-ThinkPad-L412.out
```

After this I start PIG grunt shell. Below are the log of starting of the PIG grunt shell::

```
16/08/11 10:58:07 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : LOCAL  
16/08/11 10:58:07 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : MAPREDUCE  
16/08/11 10:58:07 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Picked MAPREDUCE as the ExecType  
2016-08-11 10:58:07,102 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.16.0 (r1746530) compiled Jun 01 2016, 23:10:49  
2016-08-11 10:58:07,103 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: /home/hadoop/pig_1470893287101.log  
2016-08-11 10:58:07,145 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.Utils - Default bootup file /home/hadoop/.pigbootup not found  
2016-08-11 10:58:07,845 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable  
2016-08-11 10:58:07,876 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address  
2016-08-11 10:58:07,876 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS  
2016-08-11 10:58:07,876 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to hadoop file system at: hdfs://localhost:9000  
2016-08-11 10:58:08,427 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.PigServer - Pig Script ID for the session: PIG-default-a50ec406-53e1-42d7-bb8c-ff49c88e9118  
2016-08-11 10:58:08,427 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.PigServer - ATS is disabled since yarn.timeline-service.enabled set to false
```

After this I trigger the following command in the grunt shell.

```
data = LOAD '/pig/data.txt' USING PigStorage(',');  
STORE data INTO '/pig/dataout.txt' USING PigStorage(',');
```

After this my system crashes when the Pig starts its MapReduce phase and system restarts. P.S. I am running hadoop in Pseudo Distributed Mode.

I am right now using Lenovo Thinkpad L412 with 4 GB of RAM and Intel i5 processor.

**OS Details:**
Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit version
Kernel Version : 4.4.0-31-generic

**Hadoop Version**

Hadoop 2.7.2
Subversion https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r b165c4fe8a74265c792ce23f546c64604acf0e41
Compiled by jenkins on 2016-01-26T00:08Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum d0fda26633fa762bff87ec759ebe689c
This command was run using /home/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.2.jar

**PIG Version Details**

Apache Pig version 0.16.0 (r1746530)
compiled Jun 01 2016, 23:10:49

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you get any **errors** anywhere? So far the snippets you posted just contain warnings. -- Some general questions: 1. Does your cluster work in general (can you run a `count(*)` in hive?)  2. Does pig work in general? (can you do anything, for instance describe and dump? or process a different input file) 3. Does it matter whether you use pig with/without tez? 4. Not sure what you mean by pseudo distributed mode, but does hadoop work in other modes?

Comment: Maybe it is related to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/procps/+bug/1610499